# Deep Q learning algorithm

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning

[image]

Ok I’m a bit confused with this code, what exactly is a time step, isn’t it like when an action is performed,it goes to the next time step, and also, the gradient descent steps is a repeat until convergence, when it eventually converges we update the parameters of the target network why????, we haven’t explored other states yet

Answer (score 1):

MDPs are generally analyzed in discrete time, so basically time evolves in discrete steps. Think of it like the distinct ticks of a clock -- each of these corresponds to a timestep. In an MDP, an action as taken at each timestep.

In the algorithm you posted, where do you see anything about repeating until convergence? Usually in deep q-learning a single (or fixed amount) gradient step is carried out at each timestep.

Comment: Yeah my question is , is the gradient descent step calculated once or it keeps calculating till convergence for that time step?

Comment: Or does it only calculate once, adjust the weights for each time step

Comment: At each time step, there is only one weight update (or a fixer number of them)

Comment: Ok I also have one more question,can the weights be the same across all states , like when I enter a new state and find the target value, backpropagate and change weights, does it alter the first state, the whole point is converging the Q value to the target value

Comment: Like what I’m trying to say is , is the weight uniform across all states , will they still converge to the same value?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. You'll have a function approximator that maps states to vectors (representing the q values). The function approximator has one set of weights. You can't have a different set of weights per state, since deep q learning is designed to handle continuous state spaces -- you would need an uncountable amount of weights.

Comment: What I’m trying to say is, after a lot of episodes and we finally get a set of weights, do those set of weights hold true for all states,like once I introduce a completely new state, I get the correct Q values ?

Comment: I wish I was able to communicate this better ,what I’m trying to say is let’s say you have a y=f(x) where y=5x, the 5 value holds true for all states , is it the same for the weights

Comment: What I’m essentially trying to say is do the weights hold true for all states or one state can have one weight, and when it switches to another state it has a different state entirely or is it a constant across all stats

Comment: I'm still not really sure what you mean. Let's say your states are in R^d and your weights w are in R^n. Are you asking if w can be used to estimate the q values for each state, or if certain weights in w apply to different states? For the former, the answer is yes. For the latter, I guess that depends on the problem or what your function approximator happens to learn, but in general, all weights apply to all states.

Comment: Yes that’s exactly what I’m asking , can the weights used to approximate accurately the Q value across all states , not just for one particular state

Comment: And also if it doesn’t disturb you, can we have a chat, in case I also have other issues?

Comment: So what you’ve said is after learning , the weight we now have , can be used to accurately find the Q value of all states

Comment: Correct, assuming you have enough data to train the function approximator for all states :)

Comment: One more thing, can I reach you on any other platform ?, I have a lot of questions

Comment: another question, when the back propagation happens and the weights are updated, does it update the  Q values of the state it was in or it simply starts the loop again and moves to the next state

Comment: Updating the weights does update the Q values. If you have more questions, I encourage you to start another thread.

Comment: I started another one, check my feed